# Remove everything from a string upto a certain character and optionally a string if it follows too

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to write a regex that can remove any characters upto the first `&emsp` and if there is a `(new section)` following `&emsp` then remove that as well. But the following regex doesn't seem to work. Why? How do I correct this?

```
String removeEmsp =" &ldquo;[<centd>[</centd>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126&emsp;(new section)[<centd>]Chemotherapy services.</centd>] <centa>Cancer treatment.</centa>test snl.";
Pattern removeEmspPattern1 = Pattern.compile("(.*(&emsp;(\\(new section\\)))?)(.*)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(removeEmspPattern1.matcher(removeEmsp).replaceAll("$2"));
```

Comment: Try this `"(.*(&emsp;(\\(new section\\))?))(.*)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String removeEmsp =" &ldquo;[<centd>[</centd>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126&emsp;(new section)[<centd>]Chemotherapy services.</centd>] <centa>Cancer treatment.</centa>test snl.";
System.out.println(removeEmsp.replaceFirst("^.*?\\&emsp;(\\(new\\ssection\\))?", ""));
System.out.println(removeEmsp.replaceAll("^.*?\\&emsp;(\\(new\\ssection\\))?", ""));
```

Output:

```
[<centd>]Chemotherapy services.</centd>] <centa>Cancer treatment.</centa>test snl.
[<centd>]Chemotherapy services.</centd>] <centa>Cancer treatment.</centa>test snl.
```

It will remove everything up to "&emsp;" and optionally, the following "(new section)" text if any.

Comment: I have to use replaceAll only

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried String Split? This creates an array of strings from a string, based on a deliminator.

Once you have the string split, just select the elements of the array that you need for print statement.

[Read more here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is very long and I do not want to debug it. However the tip is that some characters have special meaning in regular expressions. For example `&` means "and". Squire brackets allow defining characters groups etc. Such characters must be escaped if you want them to be interpreted as just characters and not regex commands. To escape special character you have to write `\` in front of it. But `\` is escape character for java too, so it should be duplicate.

For example to replace ampersand by letter `A` you should write `str.replaceAll("\\&", "A")`

Now you have all information you need. Try to start from simpler regex and then expand it to what you need. Good luck.

*EDIT*
BTW parsing XML and/or HTML using regular expressions is possible but is highly not recommended. Use special parser for such formats.

Comment: I agree with the part about parsing markup languages but here I think we can consider the replaceable String as text only, and it just so happens to contain some random markup. Hence there would be no regex usage through a markup hierarchy (bad) but a brutal "find this HTML-encoded character and remove stuff" approach. That's how I see it at least.